# Cordova build change request url in angular app

Tags: javascript, android, angular, api, cordova

I've got problem with my application. I create app in angular and wrap with cordova. In android simulator request url is good but when I copy files and test in my mobile phone, url is wrong.

My request:  http://111.111.11.111/myReq   - good

On my phone, after Cordova build: file:///android_asset/www/null/login  -bad

And this my error:

POST file:///android_asset/www/null/login net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I try the solution:

1. `ng build --prod` and `cordova build --prod`
2. Rename files and directory to lowercase
3. Add line:  preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000"  or
   70000 to config.xml

This is my request:

```
userLogin(login: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

    const baseUrl = 'http://111.111.11.111/myReq'

    const httpOptions  = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'myToken',
      })
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/login`, JSON.stringify({login, password}), httpOptions);

  }
```

and nothing work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you post the js/ts code you use to make the request?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo my request I added above

Comment: It looks like for some reason the template variable is not evaluated, did you try to put the url value as a normal string?





return this.http.post<any>('http://111.111.11.111/myReq/login', JSON.stringify({login, password}), httpOptions);

Comment: @SergioRinaudo you are right! When I put normal string everything working. So how can I put baseUrl? This value is from login form input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my assumption was correct I'll give a real answer, create another variable that contains the full url that will receive the POST request

```
const requestUrl = `${baseUrl}/login` 

return this.http.post<any>(requestUrl, JSON.stringify({login, password}), httpOptions)
```

If for any reason the template variable is not working for you ( do a console log to check the value ), just concat the two strings like follow

```
const requestUrl = baseUrl + '/login'

return this.http.post<any>(requestUrl, JSON.stringify({login, password}), httpOptions)
```

Comment: Thank you for help! I fixed, problem was in place of my variable. I moved baseUrl and everything is working :)